# Database entry not showing up on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am developing my first Rails app, and I have made some database entries that are showing up in the development environment, but not in the production environment (Heroku). I have run

```
git add
git commit
git push origin master
git push heroku master
rake db:migrate
```

in the terminal.

Comment: Do you mean rake db:migrate?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant.

Comment: Ok, in order to run commands such as `rake db:migrate` on heroku you have to prefix them with `heroku run`, did you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ heroku create
$ git push heroku master
```

After running these commands, to get the application’s database to work, you’ll also have to migrate the production database:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
$ heroku open
```

if this doesn't work please show your logs.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to run

`heroku run rake db:migrate`